# Is algorithm optimal and does it satisfy specified complexity?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

Characters of given **string must be sorted according to the order defined by another pattern string.** Requirements for complexity **O(n + m)** where `n` is length of string and `m` is length of pattern.

Example:

Pattern: `1234567890AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHh`

String: `dH7ee2D6a341Fb9Ea20dhC1g7ca32Ba2Gac5f76A2g`

Result: `112222233456677790AaaaaaBbCccDddEeeFfGggHh`

Pattern has all characters of the string and each one appears in pattern only once.

My code:

```
// Instances of possible values ​​for input:
String pattern = "1234567890AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHh";
String string = "dH7ee2D6a341Fb9Ea20dhC1g7ca32Ba2Gac5f76A2g";

// Builder to collect characters for sorted result:
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

// Hash table based on characters from pattern to count occurrence of each character in string:
Map<Character, Integer> characterCount = new LinkedHashMap<>();

for (int i = 0; i < pattern.length(); i++) {
    // Put each character from pattern and initialize its counter with initial value of 0:
    characterCount.put(pattern.charAt(i), 0);
}

// Traverse string and increment counter at each occurrence of character
for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
    char ch = string.charAt(i);
    Integer count = characterCount.get(ch);
    characterCount.put(ch, ++count);
}

// Traverse completed dictionary and collect sequentially all characters collected from string
for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : characterCount.entrySet()) {
    Integer count = entry.getValue();

    if (count > 0) {
        Character ch = entry.getKey();

        // Append each character as many times as it appeared in string
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            result.append(ch);
        }
    }
}

// Get final result from builder
return result.toString();
```

Is this code optimal? Is there any way to improve this algorithm? Do I understand correctly that it satisfies the given complexity O(n + m)?

Comment: Are you assuming Java?  If, for example, characters were stored as variable-length UTF-8, then `charAt()` would not be O(1), but instead O(N).  Ditto for `append()`, which might have to discover the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if timing wise yours or mine is faster.
But here's an alternative:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
class Playground {
    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
        String pattern = "1234567890AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHh";
        String s = "dH7ee2D6a341Fb9Ea20dhC1g7ca32Ba2Gac5f76A2g";
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (char c : pattern.toCharArray()) {
            sb.append(s.replaceAll("[^" + c + "]", ""));
        }

        System.out.println(sb.toString());

        BigDecimal  elapsedTime =
            new BigDecimal( String.valueOf(System.nanoTime() - startTime)
                          )
        .divide(
            new BigDecimal( String.valueOf(1_000_000_000)
                          )
        );
        System.out.println(elapsedTime + " seconds");
    }
}
```

---

Explanation:

For each character in pattern, use a String's regex based replaceAll method to replace all characters except the current one with an empty string. Rinse and repeat. That will leave you with the count of each character in original intact, ordered by the character sequence of pattern.

---

Outputs:

```
112222233456677790AaaaaaBbCccDddEeeFfGggHh
0.021151652 seconds
```

(The timing is somewhat subjective. It came from the Sololearn Java Playground. It obviously depends on the current load on their servers)

Comment: @Emma I too was unsure about that. But thought I'd throw something else into the pot as an alternative. I am intrigued to see what else comes to the table too.